# MPI: gathering parse data to all processes

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, scientific-computing

I am parallelizing a scientific code with MPI, in which certains calculations are done in a grid (array) basis. This array stores a distributed probability that will be needed then for different computations in each of the tasks.

To distribute this calculations, i've come to the conclusion that the best way to balance the computational load is to make each individual MPI task make the computation for each position that is integer multiple of the task id (task id +1 actually). For example, in an mpi execution with four tasks (mpi_size=4), if the array has 10 elements, task 1 would compute positions 1, 5, and 9; task 2: 2, 6, and 10; task 3: 3 and 7; task 4: 4 and 8.

So, essentially in each task I am running a loop over the array with step mpi_size, and starting with an offset = (the task id + 1). Afterwards, I need all the tasks to have the results that all the other tasks have computed. This is similar to a typical mpi_allgatherv case, but as far as I understand there is no way to gather scattered data in such way, since the message of each task is then stored in clusters. Graphical explanation of what I mean (Before the MPI operation --left--, "vn" would be the values updated by the current task while the white spaces would be the values updated by other tasks):

```
Sparse computation of V (what I am trying to achieve):                       
task#1: V#1 = [v1][  ][  ][  ][v5][  ][  ][  ][v9][   ]
task#2: V#2 = [  ][v2][  ][  ][  ][v6][  ][  ][  ][V10] => V#1=V#2=V#3=V#4 = [v1][v2]...[v9][v10]
task#3: V#3 = [  ][  ][v3][  ][  ][  ][v7][  ][  ][   ]  ^
task#4: V#4 = [  ][  ][  ][v4][  ][  ][  ][v8][  ][   ]  ( HOW ??? )

Clustered computation of V    
task#1: V#1 = [v1][v2][v3][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][   ]      
task#2: V#2 = [  ][  ][  ][v4][v5][v6][  ][  ][  ][   ] => V#1=V#2=V#3=V#4 = [v1][v2]...[v9][v10]
task#3: V#3 = [  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][v7][v8][  ][   ]  ^    
task#4: V#4 = [  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][v9][v10]  ( MPI_ALLGATHERV )
```

Simplest solution I have found is to use allreduce with --for example-- MPI_SUM operation where the elements that are not calculated in each rank (white spaces above) are set to 0 in that particular rank. Other operations instead of sum come to mind, but I am trying to avoid such overhead.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want all tasks to end up with the full `{v1, ..., v10}` as describe in the text? or do you want all tasks to have a subset ad described in the "graph"?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet As described in the text. Just used the "..." to replace [v3][v4][v5][v6][v7]

Comment: if you are willing to pad your array so all ranks have the same length(e.g. 12 instead of 10 in this case), then you can use a derived datatype and `MPI_Allgather()` so all ranks end up with the same array contains values from `v1` to `v10` (plus 2 padded elements). Each task will hence send only its elements (e.g. 3 here) instead of the full array (e.g. 10 here).